# Meteor does not invalidate #if

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that loads posts based on the route parameters. If I am at `*.com/feed/` it will load all the posts that are not replies to other posts. If I am at `*.com/feed/postId` it will load the specified post plus all of its replies. Replies are just regular posts with a pointer to their parent.

I have a helper that returns the postId

```
singlePost: function () { 
  console.log('!');
  return Route.current().params.postId; 
}
```

and I use it to modify my page layout

```
{{#if singlePost}}
  {{#with onePost}}
    {{> post}}
    {{#each replies}}
      {{> post}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
{{else}}
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

On first load, and on every refresh, this works well. But if I am on the main feed displaying all of the posts, and I click one to go to that post's page, Meteor carries some of the old posts over (usually three or four). This leaves me with

`random post`

`random post`

`post I want`

`reply to post`

`random post`

Now, if I hit back, I will return to the main feed but once again I bring posts with me. This time I bring some of the random ones from before plus the post I was trying to see and maybe some of its replies. These are frozen, not reactive, not updating, and manually removing all posts from the database will remove the regular posts but not the frozen ones. If I click a post and hit back over and over again the amount of posts grows exponentially.

Refreshing clears them all immediately, but the same process quickly begins again.

If I change my page layout to not have the single post view

```
{{#unless singlePost}}
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
  {{/each}}
{{/unless}}
```

The theory here is that only if the user was on the main feed would they see posts. Click a post to view it directly, and still Meteor carries a post over. Back and forth a few times and I've got several frozen posts traveling with me.

This leads me to assume that `singlePost` is not reactive because the `#unless` is never invalidated, however the console log traces successfully on every page change. If I set the console to log the truthiness of exactly what the helper returns, it shows true and false at the correct moments --Meteor ignores this and shows the posts anyway.

If anyone has any insight into what it going on here it would be greatly appreciated

```
onePost: function() {
  var post = Router.current().params.post;

  return post ? Threads.findOne({ //Findone so I can use #with instead of #each
    _id: post
    }, {
    sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  }) : false;
},
replies: function() { //Replies are infinitely nested
  var tier = this.ancestors ? this.ancestors.length : 0;
  var size = tier + 1; //A direct child's list of ancestors 
  var query = { //will be one item longer than its parent
    ancestors: {
      $size: size
    }
  }; //And the final item will be its parent
  query['ancestors.' + tier] = this._id;

  return Threads.find(query, {
    sort: {
      timestamp: 1
    }
  });
},
posts: function() { //Posts that are not replies
  var post = Router.current().params.post;
  return post ? false : Threads.find({
    ancestors: {
      $exists: false
    }
  }, {
    sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the code for the click event?

Comment: How does `onePost` helper look? Also, you iterate over replies with same template `post` inside, so provide us with `replies` helper as well

Comment: They are all queries to the same collection specified to return relevant documents. I will update the post with their helpers

Comment: There is no click event, each post contains a link with its ID appended